# How to get files complete URL?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am calling Google Drive API from windows like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='<my folder>'+in+parents&key=<my key>
```

and it returns the files in that folder:

```
{
    "kind": "drive#fileList",
    "incompleteSearch": false,
    "files": [
        {
            "kind": "drive#file",
            "id": "1qqfAp...",
            "name": "File1.jpg",
            "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
        },
        {
            "kind": "drive#file",
            "id": "1BN7...",
            "name": "File2.jpg",
            "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
        },
        {
            "kind": "drive#file",
            "id": "1J_yu...",
            "name": "File3.jpg",
            "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
        }
    ]
}
```

These are image files so is it possible to also get full urls of each file so I can display them in my mobile app (I create with Delphi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the following query for `fields`? The additional query is `fields=files(thumbnailLink,webContentLink,webViewLink)`. The URL is as follows. Please use URLs you need from them.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='<my folder>'+in+parents&fields=files(thumbnailLink%2CwebContentLink%2CwebViewLink)&key=<my key>
```

- webContentLink

  - A link for downloading the content of the file in a browser. This is only available for files with binary content in Drive.
- webViewLink

  - A link for opening the file in a relevant Google editor or viewer in a browser.
- thumbnailLink

  - A short-lived link to the file's thumbnail, if available. Typically lasts on the order of hours. Only populated when the requesting app can access the file's content.

#### Reference :

- https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.